# How do you guarantee that your database context is disposed of properly when your lazy collection is no longer needed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm looking for a best practices kind of answer here.

Given that best practices for interacting with classes that implement `IDisposable` is via the `Using` statement - What is the best practice for using EF lazy loading with MVC?

Example controller method:

```
<HttpGet>
Public Function Schedule(ByVal id As Int64) As ActionResult

    Dim model As Schedule = Nothing
    Using database As dataContext = New dataContext
        model = (From s In database.Schedules Where s.ScheduleID = id Select s).FirstOrDefault
    End Using

    Return View(theSchedule)

End Function
```

This example makes lazy loading not work because the database [dataContext] is disposed by time the model arrives in the View.

So I guess the question is:
What are best practices for using lazy loading in MVC?  How do you guarantee that your database context is disposed of properly and that you don't cause memory leaks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, you don't need to use `Using` statements with Entity Framework data contexts.  Lazy collections is one of the reasons why.  So your code would simply be:

```
<HttpGet>
Public Function Schedule(ByVal id As Int64) As ActionResult

    Dim model As Schedule = Nothing
    Dim database As dataContext = New dataContext
    model = (From s In database.Schedules Where s.ScheduleID = id Select s).FirstOrDefault

    Return View(model)

End Function
```

Data contexts in Entity Framework are designed to open and close connections as needed, and they dispose of themselves automatically when the data context object is no longer required.

> The default behavior of DbContext is that the underlying connection is automatically opened any time is needed and closed when it is no longer needed. E.g. when you execute a query and iterate over query results using “foreach”, the call to IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() will cause the connection to be opened, and when later there are no more results available, “foreach” will take care of calling Dispose on the enumerator, which will close the connection.

The only time you would have to be careful about `IDisposable` is if you `Override` the data context's default behaviors.

#### Further Reading

[Do I always have to call Dispose on DBContext?  Nope.](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)
[Managing DbContext the right way with Entity Framework 6: an in-depth guide](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)

Comment: I'm not sure that the second half of you fourth sentence is correct: "and they dispose of themselves automatically when the data context object goes out of scope".  Since the data context falls out of scope by time its in the View, using your example the context would still be available, and thus not have disposed itself?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope.  Your right; I was a bit sloppy in my wording.  The correct description is that the DBContext disposes of itself  when it's no longer needed; i.e. the lazy collection gets fully enumerated or abandoned.  See my updates.

Comment: Thank you much for taking the time to answer this, Robert.  It is much appreciated.

Comment: Note that having a DBContext that is well-behaved without a `using` statement makes it *much nicer* to dependency-inject the DBContext, if desired.

Comment: DI is something I'll be looking into in the near future - so I'll keep that in mind.